# Negative voltage charge pump not working

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, charge-pump

I'm using the [TC7662B](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/21469a.pdf) but having a hard time using the Simple Negative Voltage Converter. I have implemented the diagram referenced in the datasheet on page 4 and has a +12V input. I'm trying to get a -12V output but reading -5V. I do not have pin 6 connected to the ground.

Do the capacitors need to be changed from 10uF in accordance with the input?
Or Is there another issue that could be causing this issue?

Comment: What do you have connected to that output?